# Characteristic function of matrix valued random variable

Tags: matrices, probability-theory

Let $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ a random variable. Denote by $\phi_X(u)$ [the characteristic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29) of $X$. It is well known that if $X$ has moments up to $k$-th order, then $\phi_X(u)$ is $k$-times continuously differentiable and we have $$\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}[X^k]=(-i)^k\cdot\frac{d^k}{du^k}\phi_X(0).$$ Similarly, for a vector valued random variable $Y:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^d$ we have $$\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}[Y^\alpha]=(-i)^{\vert\alpha\vert}\cdot\frac{\partial^{\vert\alpha\vert}}{\partial u_{\alpha_1}...\partial u_{\alpha_d}}\phi_Y(0),$$ where $Y^\alpha=Y_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots Y_d^{\alpha_d}$
and $\alpha$ is a multi index in $\mathbb{N}^d_0$, $\vert\alpha\vert=\alpha_1+\cdots+\alpha_d$.
Is there a natural analog of this formula for a matrix valued random variable $Z:\Omega\rightarrow\mathcal{S}_n$, where $\mathcal{S}_n$ is the set of symmetric $n\times n$ matrices? Can somebody guess it or give a good reference?

Comment: What kind of result are you looking for? About which expectation do you want to get information?

Comment: I have also given the extension for the formula for vector valued random variables. I hope this makes clearer what kind of generalization I want...

Comment: @DavideGiraudo: Do you want to know for what I need this formula finally?I don't understand your question...

Comment: I understand which quantity your want to express with the derivatives of the characteristic function in the case of a vector valued random variable. But I don't understand which quantity will play the role of $E[Y^{\alpha}]$ in the case of a symmetric matrix valued random variable.

Comment: That is actually also part of the question. But I think that the quantity to use here is something like $\mathbb{E}[1/n\cdot tr(Y)^k]$...